# importing pictures to python

Tags: python, image, import, turtle-graphics

I have two pictures "gif" and want to insert them as small pictures and add them to Python code. I want the picture to stay in an accurate location as well decrease it size. When i try to run this code the shell shows an error "screen isn't defined"

```
import turtle
import time
from tkinter import *

screen=turtle.Turtle()
screen=turtle.getscreen()
screen.register_shape("health.gif")
screen.penup()
screen.shape("health.gif")
screen.goto(x+50,y+150)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're getting that error... but you have a mixup with your variable names... you create a variable you call screen that is turtle.Turtle() but then you overwrite that variable by doing turtle.getscreen()

Doing:

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()
screen=t.getscreen()
screen.register_shape("health.gif")
t.penup()
t.shape("health.gif")
```

Draws a health.gif image (if that happens to be in your working directory)

Comment: @abod is getting the error because they are calling `.getscreen()` on the `turtle` module, which is undefined (or returning `None`)

Comment: jason what do you  have a suggestion for that mistake ? thank you :")

Comment: @Foon's solution is correct.  You register a shape with the `screen`, but you draw it with the `turtle`